# I am wondering what model to use

Tags: prediction, trend, database

I am trying to do an analysis of popularity growth, in particular of the rate of growth in play count for artists on an online music streaming service. I want to create a postgresql db filled with data capturing the number of plays for an artist at set intervals, and use this data to make a prediction for future growth in popularity. I am hoping for some advice about how to choose a model that will give me an easy way to make a prediction with this kind of data, and will integrate well with my postgresql database running on a rails server.

Comment: To help save this question, my advice would be to consider posting the data of interest (or some of it) as well as some tentative model(s) that you've already entertained or think would be worth entertaining. Take a one step at a time approach and show us what you've tried/not tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would probably use average member growth using the average growth of members between every performance using mean. I would do this by making a system to find the mean. E.g.  (2nd-3rd) + (4th-3rd) + (5th-4th) / 3.